# How to hide the image icon in the selector preview but show it with the selector open (Swiftui)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-picker

How to hide the image icon in the selector preview but show it with the selector open?

[image: Actual picker style]

Actual code

```
Picker("method", selection $method) {
  Label {
    Text("cash")
  } icon: {
    Image(systemName: "dollarsign.circle.fill")
  }.tag(cash)
}.pickerStyle(.menu).frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
```

I read the documentation but not found any solutions
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/picker